Prove properties of function defined as the limit of another function.
Suppose I have a non-decreasing function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and defined $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as
$$
\psi(x) = \lim_{y\to x+}\phi(y).
$$
I want to show that:
(i) $\psi(x)$ is continuous to the right.
(ii) $\psi(x)$ is non-decreasing.
This is intuitively easy, but I got stuck when writing a formal proof. The following is my attempt.
For (i), I need to show
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0+}\psi(x+\delta)-\psi(x)=0.$$This is equivalent to showing
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta>0,\vert\psi(x+\delta)-\psi(x)\vert<\epsilon.
$$
The definition of $\psi$ implies
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta_1>0,a\equiv\phi(x+\delta_1)-\psi(x)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
and,
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta_2>0,b\equiv\phi(x+\delta+\delta_2)-\psi(x+\delta)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
Then, by triangular inequality
$$
\vert\psi(x+\delta)-\psi(x)\vert < a + b < \epsilon.
$$
EOP. The questions here:

Is this proof correct? It seems weird because it implies for any $\delta$, $\psi(x+\delta)-\psi(x)<\epsilon$.
For part (ii), I want to utilize the inequality above and show for $x_2>x_1$, we have
$$
\psi(x_2)-\psi(x_1)>??>0.
$$
However, I didn't see which inequality I should use.

Edit, after @Bowei Tang's answer. I realize what is wrong with my previous proof. I rewrote the proof for part (i) and I think it is correct.
For (i), I need to show
$$\lim_{z \to 0+}\psi(x+z)-\psi(x)=0.$$This is equivalent to showing
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta>0, \forall 0<z<\delta, \vert\psi(x+z)-\psi(x)\vert<\epsilon.
$$
The definition of $\psi$ implies
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta_1>0,\forall 0<t_1<\delta_1,\vert\phi(x+t_1)-\psi(x)\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
This holds similarly for arbitrary $z>0$,i.e.,
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta_2>0,\forall 0<t_2<\delta_2,\vert\phi(x+z+t_2)-\psi(x+z)\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
Take $z\in (0,\delta_1)$ and arbitrarily small $t_2>0$ such that $0<z+t_2<\delta_1$. Then we have both
$$
\vert\phi(x+z+t_2)-\psi(x+z)\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{2},\vert\phi(x+z+t_2)-\psi(x)\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
Then, triangular inequality implies the desired result
$$
\forall \epsilon \exists 0<\delta<\delta_1 \forall 0<z<\delta,\vert\psi(x+z)-\psi(x)\vert<\epsilon
$$

For $(1)$: The eighth line is wrong, it is not equivalent to that, but this: $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, s.t. for\ all\ 0<h<\delta \implies |\psi(x+h)-\psi(x)|<\epsilon$$
For $(2)$: given arbitrary $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$ with $x_2>x_1$, we have:  ([*],[**] for notation)
$$\psi(x_2)-\psi(x_1)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_2^{+}}\phi(x)[*]-\lim\limits_{x\to x_1^{+}}\phi(x)[**]$$
By definition, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0,$ such that whenever $x_2<x<x_2+\delta$, we have $|\phi(x)-\psi(x_2)|<\epsilon$.
Similarly, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0,$ such that whenever $x_1<x<x_1+\delta$, we have $|\phi(x)-\psi(x_1)|<\epsilon$.
If ${\psi(x_2)-\psi(x_1)}=0$, nothing to prove.
If ${\psi(x_2)-\psi(x_1)}\neq0$, by choosing $\delta=\frac{x_2-x_1}{2}$, since $\phi$ is non-decreasing, we have $\phi(x)<\epsilon+\psi(x_1)$[**] and $\phi(x)>-\epsilon+\psi(x_2)$[*], which results in $$\psi(x_2)-\epsilon\geq\psi(x_1)+\epsilon,\forall \epsilon>0\implies\psi(x_2)-\psi(x_1)>0$$
Thus, we conclude that $\psi(x_2)-\psi(x_1)\geq0$ when $x_2>x_1.$

Thank you for the clear answer! Somehow I missed a crucial part, i.e. the inequality holds within a ball. I also realize what is wrong with my proof for part (1).

@mephist Much more clear now.

@mephist https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

@AnneBauval, hi, I read the rules there. Do you mean I should not say thanks in the comments or should I consider accepting the answer (or both)?

Hi, both but mainly the 2nd.
